# override supportRtl value

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I'd like to override a `supportRtl=true` value that is set by some library I plan to integrate.

I assume something of the following statement will do the trick

```
<meta-data
   android:name="supportRtl"
   android:value="false"
   tools:replace="android:value" />
```

Looking for the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:supportsRtl` is an attribute of the [`<application>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html) tag.

```
<application
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    tools:replace="android:supportsRtl" />
```

Comment: Or just create PRs for removing these attributes, for all the libraries defining this. A manifest file of a library should not set such information at all. Maybe to false, maybe.

Comment: thanks! works fine. You have a typo, it's supports, not support.